# running video processing python code on google colaboratory using gpu k80

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using an open source code from github for face detection uploaded to google colaboratory that runs k80 GPU. I believe I have installed and imported the libraries needed such as mxnet-cu90 and when I run the code I get the error listed below which I am not sure if it is a path problem or k80 does not support it or something else.

```
OSError: libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do we do imports differently in colab such as `import mxnet as mx`

It is my first attempt at colab and I run the code in the notebook cell as follows:

`!python VideoProcessor.py`

The VideoProcessor.py code runs as follows:

```
  File "VideoProcessor.py", line 7, in <module>
    from retinaface import RetinaFace
  File "../thirdparty/insightface/RetinaFace/retinaface.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mxnet as mx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mxnet/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mxnet/context.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 213, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 204, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```